ODBC driver Snowflake SSIS
I am having an issue with my ODBC connection on SSIS and Snowflake. After configuring and installing both the 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC drivers simultaneously, I tested each one individually, but I encountered the same error.
The error in question is that my connection is successfully established between SSIS and Snowflake; I am able to display the tables from the SSIS ODBC Source component. However, when attempting to map the columns, I do not see any columns, and I no longer see any data in the connection manager.
enter image description here here is the image

when i use Execute sql commande i have this issue : <ResultSetType_Rowset> I have correctly set the complete result set as Resultset. However, when I use the ADO.NET Source Manager, it works perfectly fine

Why you can't use ADO.NET source ? Do you have more then 1 table with same name in different schemas ? When we use ODBC with snowflake there are some limitations we can't use the same name of an entity which appeared in more then 1 schema. Post the screenshots for better clarification.

First check which ODBC connection you are using try with both 32 bit and 64 bit one by one.

I finally use the ADO.NET Source it works perfect.

Provide more details on that issue, Only use 64 bit ODBC data source and which method you are using to retrieve the data, try to execute SQL command instead of directly selecting table
e.g:
Select column_name 
From DB_Name.Schema_Name.Table_Name

